# Show that a bounded subset of $C^1[a, b]$ is equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a bounded subset of $C^1[a,\ b]$. If $f\in S$, $\exists M>0$ s.t. $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in[a,\ b]$. In addition, $f$ and $f'$ are continuous on $[a,\ b]$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Counterexample: $f_n(x) = \sin( \pi n x)$ on $[0,1]$. We have $|f_n| \le 1$, but $|f_n(x_n)| =1$ for $x_n =1/n$. Thus, we can not have $|f_n(0)-f_n(x)| <1$ for $|x| < \delta$, where $\delta>0$ is independent of $n$.

Comment: @p4sch The derivatives $f_n'$ form an unbounded set though. I would guess that the norm being used here is $\Vert f \Vert = \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)| + \sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f'(x)|$

Comment: Yes, I know. The questioner doesn't said anything about the chosen norm on $C^1[a,b]$.

Comment: Indeed. Actually the fact that questioneer mentions the existence of $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ seems to suggest that he's not using the norm I mentioned.

Comment: It could be that I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: You should mention the norm you are using. Otherwise we cannot know what boundedness means.

Comment: You say $S$ is a bounded subset of $C^1[a,b]$. Unless told to assume a nonstandard context, this should mean there exists $M>0$ such that $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $f \in S$ and all $x \in [a,b]$. In which case the result follows from the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I think what has everyone confused is how Thomas explicitly mentions that each function $f \in S$ is bounded which is a significantly weaker assumption then what we would otherwise consider "Let $S$ be a bounded subset of $C^1[a,b]$" to mean. Moreover, $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ already implies that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the norm $$|f|:= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)| + \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f'(x)|$$ on $C^1[a,b]$, then a set is bounded if and only if $|f| \le M$ and $|f'| \le M$ for all $f \in S$. Thus  for all $y >x$
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \int_x^y |f'(t)| \, dt \le M |y-x|.$$
This proves already that $M$ is equicontinuous.

$C^1[a,b]$ with this norm is a Banach space. Note that $|f|_2 := \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ is another norm and now $C^1[a,b]$ is not a Banach space. In this case, the statement is false. Take as in my comment $f_n(x)=\sin(\pi n x)$ on $[0,1]$. We have $|f_n| \le 1$, but $|f_n(x_n)|=1$ for $x_n=1/n$. Thus, we can not have $|f_n(0)−f_n(x)|<1$ for $|x| < \delta$, where $\delta >0$ is independent of $n$.

However, this property doesn't depend on the completness: We can take
$$|f|_3:= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)| + \sqrt{\int_a^b |f'(x)|^2 \, dx}.$$
And here we also have that a bounded set is equicontinuous. (We can argue as above in combination with the Hölder inequality.) But the space is not complete with this norm! (Just take sequence $g_n$ of continuous functions with $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^2$, where $g$ is not continuous and set $f_n(t):= \int_a^t g_n(h) \, dh$. Note that $|f_n-f_m|_\infty \le \sqrt{(b-a)} \|g_n - g_m\|_{L^2} $.)

Comment: Good answer (+1)